# Only "puts" one line to a text document

Tags: ruby

The code I'm working with at the moment is supposed to spit back every line of information in one text document that contains the word "DEBUG" and then paste it in a new text document titled "debug.txt".

For whatever reason it is only printing the final line into the new text document and I have no clue why. However, another function is to  spit back every line to the command terminal, and it does that successfully, it just won't write  them all to the file.

```
log_file = File.open("main_file.rb")

File.readlines(log_file).each do |line|
  if line.include? "DEBUG" 
    puts line
        File.open("debug.txt", "w") do |out|
            out.puts line
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: It is doing that because every time you are iterating lines you are opening the file again.  Put the File.open outside the readlines block.

Comment: Stop opening the file; leave it open. Or open it in append mode, but that's likely to be much slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting the file every time you find a DEBUG line in `main_file`. You have your blocks backwards. The `File.open('debug.txt')` should be outside of the `File.readlines`.

Like this:

```
log_file = File.open("main_file.rb")

File.open("debug.txt", "w") do |out|
  File.readlines(log_file).each do |line|
    if line.include? "DEBUG" 
      puts line
      out.puts line
    end
  end
end
```

You could also open the file in append mode by passing `'a'` instead of `'w'` in your `File.open('debug.txt')` call but this would be needlessly reopening the file every time you find a line that contains DEBUG in it. It would be better to open the debug file once for writing and using the file handle from there on as I show above.

Answer (score 1):

Write it like this:

```
File.open("debug.txt", "w") do |out|
  File.foreach("main_file.rb") do |line|
    if line['DEBUG']
      puts line
      out.puts line
    end
  end
end
```

You need to:

1. Open the output file.
2. Iterate over the lines in the input file.
3. For each line, check to see if it contains the string you want.
4. If so, write it.
5. Loop until the input file is completely read.
6. Close the output file.

Notice I don't open the file for output as a single step. Ruby's use of blocks are really handy: By passing a block to `open`, Ruby will close the file when the block exits, avoiding the problem of open files hanging around to clutter memory or consume available file handles.

Use [`foreach`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-c-foreach) to read the file. It reads a single line at a time and is extremely fast. It's also scalable, which means it'll work for a one-line file or a 10-million line file equally well. Using [`readlines`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-c-readlines), as in your code, results in Ruby loading the entire file into memory, splitting it into separate lines, then iterating over them. That can cause real problems if your input file exceeds available RAM.

`line['DEBUG']` is shorthand for "do a substring match for this text". See [`String#[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) for more information.

Comment: Great answer. I humbly suggest yours be the correct one.